# How can I read a reg_qword in winreg in python 3.4?

Tags: python, windows, registry, python-3.4, winreg

I inserted a registry key, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test\test_qword` of type `REG_QWORD` and value `20150509091344` (`0x1253a7efba10`).

I then tried to load it using `winreg` with the following code in Python 3.4:

```
import winreg
key_dir = r"SOFTWARE\test"
reg = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key_dir, 0,
                     winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY+winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
test_dir = list(winreg.QueryValueEx(reg, r'test_qword'))[0]
print(test_dir)
ans = "".join(map(lambda b: format(b, "02x"), test_dir))
print(ans)
print(int(ans, 16))
```

and got the following console output:

```
b'\x10\xba\xef\xa7S\x12\x00\x00'
10baefa753120000
1205539352207294464
```

Which is not my original value. How can I retrieve my original value with `winreg`?

Comment: I realized that I need to convert the information in the following way:`code test = ans[-2:]
for i in range(int(len(ans)/2)):
 test += ans[-(i*2+2):-(i*2)]
print(int(test, 16))` but maybe there's a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote interprets the value as a big-endian-stored integer. However, [`REG_QWORD` is stored as a little-endian number.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There's a much easier way to convert the `bytes` value of a 64-bit integer: using [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack). The format `'<q'` will read a signed 64-bit little-endian integer:

```
>>> struct.unpack('<q', b'\x10\xba\xef\xa7S\x12\x00\x00')
(20150509091344,)
```

And if you wanted to read it as big-endian:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>q', b'\x10\xba\xef\xa7S\x12\x00\x00')
(1205539352207294464,)
```

you can see it gives you the same incorrect value you were getting in your code.

More information on the format codes for `struct.unpack()` and its inverse, `struct.pack()`, are in [the docs for the `struct` module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings)